# Can I store Outlook's PST files in Dropbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, dropbox, pst

I am wondering if there are any potential issues in moving large Outlook PST files (e.g. a few 3–5GB Outlook files) into Dropbox?

The files are periodically accessed / altered and might increase marginally in size.

Comment: The files would still be local I don't see how it would cause a problem.  The only problem ( not connected to Dropbox you have ) is having Outlook load .PST 3-5GB in size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [Dropbox help centre](https://www.dropbox.com/help/52/en), Dropbox doesn't sync files that are in use, so your PST files probably wouldn't sync in real-time. They would only sync when the user closes Outlook. However, when it does sync it will [only do a differential copy](https://www.dropbox.com/help/8/en) (only the changes to the file are copied), so it won't have to re-upload the entire file every time.